# how to connect table with his checkboxes?

Tags: javascript

i want to check all checkbox in first table if i press on first checkbox and i want to check all checkbox in second table if i press on second checkbox , but when i press on first or second checkbox it checkbox all in two table

```
function checkAll(t,ele) {
        var table= document.getElementById(t);

     var checkboxes = ("table td input[type=checkbox]");

     if (ele.checked) {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = true;
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox"   id="chkbjan" onchange="checkAll('datatablejan',this)" name="chk[]"><span>January Checked</span>

Comment: <input type="checkbox"   id="chkbfeb" onchange="checkAll('datatablejan',this)" name="chk[]"><span>February Checked</span>

Comment: Start by fixing the two inputs that have the same ID. IDs must be unique.

Comment: what else, how to connect checkbox with specific table?

Comment: What table? Can you show the HTML that shows the tables?

Comment: Line var checkboxes = ("table td input[type=checkbox]"); makes no sense to me. It's just a string, you are not selecting anything..

Comment: <table border="1" id="datatablejan">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Monday </th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wedenesday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox">4</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ><span class="mg-l-10">9</span></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"><span class="mg-l-10">11</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: @jack In your second comment you need to change the first parameter being passed to checkAll() to 'datatablefeb'. Assuming there is a table with that ID.

Comment: Edit your question with html and maybe a working example, don't post it in a comment

Comment: dear  Wimanicesir, how can i select table with his checkboxes. 
var checkboxes=....?

Comment: i tried to edit html here but it is not success to post. i do not know why

Comment: @jack You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58306161/edit) your question and add it as code block or snippet (if executable).

Comment: var checkboxes = ("table td input[type=checkbox]"); And how shoul the thing kno which table to act on = ? I think this selectoe will get all checkboxes. In any case. Try to add a identfier class.  You may add a css rule which will be exactly your select rule and colorize them green. if this will also make both green then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all checkboxes within a table by class name

```
document.getElementById("tableId").getElementsByClassName("checkboxclass");
```

Full snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById('toggleOnFirst').onclick = function(){
  checkAll('firstTable', true)
}

document.getElementById('toggleOffFirst').onclick = function(){
  checkAll('firstTable', false)
}

document.getElementById('toggleOnSecond').onclick = function(){
  checkAll('secondTable', true)
}

document.getElementById('toggleOffSecond').onclick = function(){
  checkAll('secondTable', false)
}

function checkAll(table, status) {
  // Get all checkboxes by class within a table
 var checkboxes = document.getElementById(table).getElementsByClassName("check");
  
  // Loop all checkboxes and check / uncheck them
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
   var checkbox = checkboxes[i]
    checkbox.checked = status;
  }
  
}
```

```html
 <table id="firstTable" style="width:100%" >
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<button id="toggleOnFirst">
Toggle on
</button>

<button id="toggleOffFirst">
Toggle off
</button>

 <table id="secondTable" style="width:100%" >
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<button id="toggleOnSecond">
Toggle on
</button>

<button id="toggleOffSecond">
Toggle off
</button>
```